Shapiro-Wilk vs box plot for normality distribution
I ran the Shapiro-Wilk test for normality (n=8) in order to decide whether to use a parametric or non-parametric test for significance test. The result says my data is normally distributed (p >0.05) but visual inspection of the box plot is not indicative of normal distribution. The sample size is small so I am wondering if it is because of that but now I am not sure whether to proceed with Repeated Measures ANOVA or Friedman Test.

Is there any reason you only have 8 observations? It's going to be challenging to do anything with such few data points. It would be important to know what you seek to test with this data, or else nobody can give any real answers.

My data is looking at DNA concentration from three different sample types (petrous bone, femur and teeth) from eight cadavers. The nature of such studies mean that we have limited donated cadavers to work with. I want to establish if there is a significance between the three different samples in order to establish the most suitable sample material with high DNA conc.


Your distribution cannot actually be normal (the variable, being a concentration is positive), so the null of the Shapiro-Wilk is false. A non-rejection (which is very much on the cards at n=8) is a type II error. This is of no consequence, since it doesn't address the question you needed to answer there, which is about the suitability of some test that assumes normality 2. parametric doesn't mean "assumes a normal distribution". 3. beware changing your hypothesis when you change your test 4. Boxplots are not useful as a way of assessing distributional shape - even potentially misleading



It's not clear to me that a test is the best way to approach what it sounds like you're trying to do.


See Glen's comments.
With N = 8 there is very  little you can do.  More generally, if you had a larger N, a good way to test normality is a quantile normal plot. Another choice is a density plot.

For ANOVA, the normality test is on the residuals, not on the raw DNA concentration data. So you should have at least 3*8=24 observations in your residuals? Which dataset are you testing for normality?
